# Wildfly 10.1, JMS lookup with IPv6

Tags: jms, wildfly, netty, ipv6, activemq-artemis

I have a working IPv4 configuration for using ActiveMQ in a rich java client with Wildfly 10.1 as server. I tried to switch to IPv6 and it doesn't work anymore. The problem is, that the context lookup retrieves a ServerLocator object, that contains the IPv6 scope id, e.g.:
[fd00::d7dc:b4cc:2e2a:ea1%enp0s3]

But this scope is only valid on the server. When the client tries to connect to the server in the ServerLocator it obviously cannot, since the enp0s3 is the interface on the server and not on the client. When I remove the scope in debug mode the application runs again without problem. So it is only the wrong scope...

Is there any way to setup the server, to only send the address without scope? The server runs on Java 8 and OS is Centos 7.

My client code is:

```
        String JMS_CONNECTION_FACTORY_JNDI = "jms/RemoteConnectionFactory";
        Context context = getApplicationManager().getConnectionHandler().getContext();
        TopicConnectionFactory cf = (TopicConnectionFactory) context.lookup(JMS_CONNECTION_FACTORY_JNDI);
        topicConnection = cf.createTopicConnection();
```

The context properties are set correctly and work for IPv4.

The config is pretty standard:

```
   <interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
 </socket-binding-group>
```

Messaging:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:1.0">
        <server name="default">
            <security enabled="false"/>
            <security-setting name="#">
                <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-durable-queue="true" delete-durable-queue="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
            </security-setting>
            <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10"/>
            <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
            <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
                <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
            </http-connector>
            <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
            <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
                <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
            </http-acceptor>
            <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
            <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
            <jms-queue name="simulationServerQueue" entries="queue/simulationServerQueue java:/jms/queue/simulationServerQueue"/>
            <jms-queue name="simulationWrapperQueue" entries="queue/simulationWrapperQueue java:/jms/queue/simulationWrapperQueue"/>
            <jms-topic name="StatusMessaging" entries="topic/StatusMessaging java:/jms/queue/StatusMessaging"/>
            <jms-topic name="SimulationMessaging" entries="topic/SimulationMessaging java:/jms/queue/SimulationMessaging"/>
            <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
            <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
            <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>
        </server>
```

and properties:

```
jboss.bind.address=[fd00::d7dc:b4cc:2e2a:ea1]
java.rmi.server.hostname=[fd00::d7dc:b4cc:2e2a:ea1]
jboss.http.port=8080
```

The same context (retrieved by getConnectionHandler().getContext();) and configuration works for EJB lookup without problem. I can lookup the interfaces via JNDI and execute code on the server.

Only the topic connection (with ActiveMQ) is affected. And only because of the SCOPE. If I remove the scope (enp0s3) in debug mode in the URL in ActiveMQConnectionFactory.readExternal(..), ActiveMQ works.

## Update to Wildfly 11

I tried the same with Wildfly 11.0.0.Final The error changes to

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: no such interface enp0s3
at java.net.Inet6Address.initstr(Inet6Address.java:487)
at java.net.Inet6Address.<init>(Inet6Address.java:408)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1181)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1076)
at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:146)
```

So the problem is the same. The scope id is not stripped for the JMS client.

## EDIT Centos 7

I did a small program to check the java implementation to get a InetAddress:

```
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    while (interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
        NetworkInterface netInterface = interfaces.nextElement();
        Enumeration<InetAddress> address = netInterface.getInetAddresses();
        while (address.hasMoreElements()) {
            InetAddress addr = address.nextElement();
            if (addr instanceof Inet6Address) {
                Inet6Address inet6addr = (Inet6Address) addr;
                if (!inet6addr.isLinkLocalAddress() && !inet6addr.isLoopbackAddress())
                    System.out.println(netInterface.getName() +":"+ inet6addr.isLinkLocalAddress() +":"+ inet6addr +" - "+ inet6addr.getScopedInterface());

            }
        }
    }
```

On windows it returns:

```
eth2:false:/fd00:0:0:0:309c:ae5c:b57c:da62 - null
```

So no scope set. On centos 7:

```
enp0s3:false:/fd00:0:0:0:d7dc:b4cc:2e2a:ea1%enp0s3 - name:enp0s3 (enp0s3)
```

So scope is set on centos even though it is not link local. I assume something similar is used during lookup? Any ideas?

## UPDATE Workaround

Since this seems to be a problem with NettyConnector, I found a workaround. This is not nice, but it seems to work:

```
        String JMS_CONNECTION_FACTORY_JNDI = "jms/RemoteConnectionFactory";
        Context context = getApplicationManager().getConnectionHandler().getContext();
        TopicConnectionFactory cf = (TopicConnectionFactory) context.lookup(JMS_CONNECTION_FACTORY_JNDI);
        // TODO: Remove if fixed in Netty
        // THIS IS A PATCH SINCE NETTYCONNECTOR DOES NOT STRIP IPv6 SCOPE
        if (cf instanceof ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory) {
            TransportConfiguration[] o = ((ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory) cf).getStaticConnectors();
            for (TransportConfiguration tc : o) {
                String host = tc.getParams().get("host").toString();
                tc.getParams().put("host", stripScope(host));
            }
        }
```

The stripScope is defined as:

```
private String stripScope(String ipV6host) {
    // only if it contains a %
    if (ipV6host != null && ipV6host.contains("%")) {
        // Strip [ and ] if any
        if (ipV6host.charAt(0) == '[') {
            if (ipV6host.length() > 2 && ipV6host.charAt(ipV6host.length() - 1) == ']') {
                ipV6host = ipV6host.substring(1, ipV6host.length() - 1);
            } else {
                // no closing ] return input value
                return ipV6host;
            }
        }
        if (Character.digit(ipV6host.charAt(0), 16) != -1 || (ipV6host.charAt(0) == ':')) {
            // see if it is IPv6 address
            byte[] addr;
            if (IPAddressUtil.textToNumericFormatV4(ipV6host) == null
                    && (addr = IPAddressUtil.textToNumericFormatV6(ipV6host)) != null) {
                try {
                    return InetAddress.getByAddress(addr).getHostAddress();
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return ipV6host;
}
```

This needs to be tested... is just a first working hack... any comments / better solutions are welcome.

Comment: You should only use the scope on Link-Local addresses (`fe80::/10`). The address you have is a ULA address, not a Link-Local address.

Comment: The scope is returned by the lookup! I have not set the scope anywhere in the config. Connecting to EJBs via the same context / lookup works. It is really only a ActiveMQ / netty problem

Comment: It's a poorly generated ULA address, too. That might be the underlying cause of the problem. Is this your home network? If so, [generate](https://www.ultratools.com/tools/rangeGenerator) a new proper ULA prefix.

Comment: Are you specifying a bind address when you start Wildfly? Can you share your Wildfly config? The Wildfly configuration will determine what is passed back to the client doing the JNDI lookup, but you haven't provided any details on that point.

Comment: There is a bit of code in Artemis which is supposed to strip the scope ID from the IPv6 address - https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/master/artemis-core-client/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/core/remoting/impl/netty/NettyConnector.java#L712.  Perhaps this code isn't working in your case.  Could you test it?

Comment: Yes, this is not working... 
InetAddress inetAddress = ((InetSocketAddress) remoteDestination).getAddress();
returns null, since only the hostname but not the adress is set in the object

Comment: This already fails in the new InetSocketAddress(host, port); --> This tries to resolve the Address and throws an UnknownHostException since the Scope (ethernet interface) is not known on the client and the address is not set in the InetSocketAddressHolder

Comment: I opened https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-1701 and sent a pull-request which should take care of the issue in Artemis 2.5.